# Wordpress: Add dynamic class to body based on what page is displayed

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to add a class to specific pages that are under the following route: www.mydomain.com/special/...

So whenever /special/ is in the current url, i thought I could add a class to the theme header.php file:

```
<body id="landing-page" <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

Would this be the way to go? How could I get the current page url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add below snippet to your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'custom_class' );
function custom_class( $classes ) {
    if ( is_page('special') ) {
        $classes[] = 'myclass';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Or

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'custom_class' );
    function custom_class( $classes ) {
        if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "special") !== false){
            $classes[] = 'myclass';
        }
        return $classes;
    }
```

Comment: Is that it? as nothing seems to happen even when i simply return ['random-class'];

Comment: First snippet only work with page name spacial. Second one work with each url that have word spacial

Comment: It should 100% work. Change its priority then check

Comment: add_filter( 'body_class', 'custom_class', 99);

Comment: Add 99 ad i have added above then check please

Comment: Have great day. Thank you